# How to use event.x and event.y as variable that i use every where

Tags: python, tkinter

i try to many times to use event.x & event.y  out side the function but nothing works

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def start_mouse_press(event):
    print(f"starting mouse at {event.x, event.y}")


def stop_mouse_press(event):
    print(f"stopping mouse at {event.x, event.y}")


root.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', start_mouse_press)
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', stop_mouse_press)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not specifically neat, you can use global variables to store the start position for usage later.

Consider the below example

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

start_pos = None

def start_mouse_press(event):
    global start_pos
    start_pos = (event.x, event.y)

def stop_mouse_press(event):
    print(f"Start Pos {start_pos}\nEnd Pos {event.x, event.y}")


root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", start_mouse_press)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stop_mouse_press)
```

The start position is recorded so that when the mouse button is released, both the start and end positions can be printed.

Answer (score -1):

You will never be able to access event outside of the function of which event is an argument.

This is a matter of scope, if you wish to use event elsewhere, pass event as an argument to the next function you wish to use it in.

Comment: While it's literally true that you can't access the `event` _variable_ outside of the function, you can access the event _object_ by assigning it to a global variable. And given that they appear they want to use the values in the `stop_mouse_press` event handler, passing it from one method to another can't work since they aren't calling that function directly.